# How to manipulate relations without fetching the related entities in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible in EntityFramework 6 to add/remove related entities without actual fetching the related entities?

I was trying:

```
var a = new EntityA()
a.B = new EntityB { Id = 2 }; 
db.Entry(a).State = EntityState.Added;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The entity with Id already exists in DB. My attempt fails with the following exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'EntityB' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: How do you know the Id of the related entity if you hadn't already fetched it?

Comment: It is a web app. I have fetched that it the previous request (when I was rendering a form). Then I've received that via ajax/websockets from a combo.

Comment: I haven't had the need to myself, but you should be able to attach your skeleton `EntityB` to the context. It gets the `Unmodified` flag so EF ought to leave it be when you save changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your exact error you need to set `db.Entry( b ).State` of the new `B` entity to `Unchanged` (your code results in `Added`)

Comment: Actually, I use set.Attach() instead.

Comment: The State should be "Unchanged" instead of "Unmodified"